# Mutually disjoint implying complements in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

No homework tag because it is just practice for a final, not for marks:

$\text{Let $S, T \subseteq U$. If $S \bigcap T= \emptyset$, then $S$  and $T$ :}$

A) are always complements of each other in $U$,

B) are mutually disjoint,

C) have no elements in common,

D) choices B and C,

E) none of these choices

I am very confused as I thought the answer should be all of A B and C, but unless the answer is E, which would be a misleading answer for no reason, that is incorrect.

My train of thought is that, since $S\bigcap T = \emptyset $ they definitely do not have any elements in common. They must be mutually disjoint as there is no intersection. They should also be complements of each other?? Where am I going wrong? Thank you!

Edit: Thank you everyone! I had the wrong understanding of the definition of complement. All your answers/comments were helpful, thanks.

Comment: Let $S = \{0\}, T = \{1\}, U = \{0,1,2\}$. Then $S$ and $T$ satisfy $S \cap T = \emptyset$, but are not complements of each other in $U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complement means that $S\cup T=U$. Is this necessarily the case?

Answer (score 3):

$U$ can be larger than $S \cup T$, i.e. there can be elements in $U$ that are not in either $S$ or $T$.  So the complement of S then ($S^c$) is then larger than $T$ so $S$ and $T$ will not be complements of each other.